# Meaning of Sentence Using 〜ほど…はない

Tags: grammar

What does this sentence from my grammar textbook mean?

わたしは今日ほど楽しい試験をこれまでしたことはない。

I guess it means "I haven't had a test as fun as today's so far."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is basically correct. It might be more grammatical to translate it as "I've never taken/had a test as fun as today's (so far)."

[time expression]ほど[adjectival phrase] = "as [adj] as [time]"

～ことはない is the verb ending that indicates "have never [verbed].

> 昨日ほど怖いお化け屋敷を見たことはない。
>   I've never seen a haunted house as scary as yesterday's.
>
> 去年ほど面白いワールドカップを見たことはない。
>   I've never seen a World Cup as fun as last year's.